# Replace a value in one column depending on the value of another column

Tags: r

I got very good help earlier concerning *"The value in one column depends in the value of another column"*, I wanted all values with 2 in q1 to give 0 in column q2. One of the suggestions solved this:`df$q2[df$q1 == 2] <- 0`

Now I wonder how to do when I only want to replace when q1=2 and q2= NA. Because sometimes there is a value in q2 when q1 is 2, and that I want to keep.

Thanks in advance! :)

```
a <- rep(c(300,450), each=c(3,3))
q1 <- rep(c(1,1,2,1,1,2),2)
q2 <- c(100,40,"",80,30,"" , 45,78,"",20,58,"")

df <- cbind(a,q1,q2)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df
     a q1  q2
1  300  1 100
2  300  1  40
3  300  2  30  
4  450  1  80
5  450  2  35
6  450  2    
7  300  1  45
8  300  1  78
9  300  2    
10 450  1  20
11 450  1  58
12 450  2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[q1 == 2 & is.na(q2), q2 := 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

To represent empty values, you could use `NA` instead of `""`

```
a <- rep(c(300,450), each=c(3,3))
q1 <- rep(c(1,1,2,1,1,2),2)
q2 <- c(100,40,NA,80,30,NA, 45,78,NA,20,58,NA)
df <- data.frame(a,q1,q2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then you can check for `NA` values by adding another condition

```
df$q2[df$q1 == 2 & is.na(df$q2)] <- 0
```

However, currently for the code to work on your data you might need

```
df$q2[df$q1 == 2 & df$q2 == ""] <- 0
```